# Within IAM, can I restrict a group of users to access/launch/terminate only certain EC2 AMIs or instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, amazon-iam

What the title says.

Within the master AWS account, I have several personal accounts, i.e. [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) users. I would like to assign certain IAM users to groups and prevent them from terminating certain [Amazon EC2 instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Instances.html), de-registering certain [Amazon Machine Images (AMIs)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html), etc.

I don't mind if they're playing with their own stuff, but I don't want them to touch my stuff.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Update

AWS has just announced [Resource-Level Permissions for Amazon EC2 and Amazon RDS](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/07/resource-permissions-for-ec2-and-rds-resources.html) to address this long standing shortcoming of IAM support within EC2 and RDS (in comparison to other AWS services, see my original answer below for details/background):

> Today we are making IAM even more powerful with the introduction of resource-level permissions for [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2) and [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds). [...]
>
> On the EC2 side, you can now construct and use IAM policies to control
>   access to EC2 instances, EBS volumes, images, and Elastic IP
>   addresses. [...]
>
> Here are just a few of things that you can do:
>
> - Allow users to act on a limited set of resources within a larger, multi-user EC2 environment.
> - Set different permissions for "development" and "test" resources.
> - Control which users can terminate which instances.
> - Require additional security measures, such as MFA authentication, when acting on certain resources.

This solves a plethora of security complications and enables quite a few new use cases as well.

Furthermore, *EC2 policy statements can include reference to tags on EC2 resources*, which allows to *use the same tagging model and schema for permissions and for billing reports*. Finally, there's an *expanded set of condition tags [...] including ec2:Region, ec2:Owner, and ec2:InstanceType*, see [Condition Keys for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#amazon-ec2-keys) for details.

### Solution

Here's a variation of [Example 3: Allow users to stop and start only particular instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ex3) for the use case at hand, which *allows users to start and stop [and terminate] only the instances that have the tag "department=dev"*:

```js
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:StopInstances", 
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:TeminateInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/department": "dev"
        }
      }
    }
   ]
}
```

#### Caveat

Support for resource-level permissions is restricted to the following set of actions on the indicated resources still, which excludes parts of the use case (e.g. *de-registering AMIs*) - the confidence in the foundation for this *complex and far-reaching feature*  is apparently high enough though to announce that they *plan to add support for additional APIs throughout the rest of 2013* (AWS doesn't usually publish any roadmaps):

> - Instances - Reboot, Start, Stop, Terminate.
> - EBS Volumes - Attach, Delete, Detach.

---

## Original Answer

I'm afraid this isn't possible the way you'd like to do it (and many others for that matter, including myself).

### Problem

You want to restrict access to a particular service's *resources* rather than its *actions* - while [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) supports both in principle, not every AWS product/service offers restrictions based on resources yet; unfortunately [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) is one of these and even featured as an example for this very difference, see [Integrating with Other AWS Products](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Using_SpecificProducts.html):

> The following table summarizes whether you can grant IAM permissions
>   that control access to a service's actions, resources, or both. For
>   example, **you can use IAM to control which Amazon EC2 actions users
>   have access to, but you can't use IAM to control users' access to
>   AMIs, volumes, instances, etc.** *[emphasis mine]*

#### (Partial) Workaround

Depending on the needs of the other accounts, you *might* still be able to at least limit their ability to perform those actions considered destructive - you can explore the available actions via the [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html), for example:

- `ec2:DeregisterImage` - obvious effect, when denied for a user/group
- `ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute` - this would help via [Enabling Termination Protection for an Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_ChangingDisableAPITermination.html), when denied for a user/group:

> By default, you can terminate any instances you launch. If you want to
>   prevent accidental termination of the instance, you can enable
>   termination protection for the instance.

That is, once you've enabled termination protection, anyone without permission to use `ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute` cannot terminate these instances at all.

Obviously the respectively restricted accounts won't be able to facilitate those calls for their own resources anymore.

Furthermore this won't prevent them from running a fancy *Cluster Compute Eight Extra Large Instance* or so, incurring respective costs in turn ;)

### Alternative Approach

Depending on your setup/environment you might want to look into *Consolidated Billing* instead, which essentially provides a way to gather one or many AWS accounts under another one, which is paying for the resources used by the others.

While this is primarily an accounting feature, it can be used to separate areas of concern as well - for example, it's quite common to facilitate separate development and production accounts to achieve respectively independent operation, not the least regarding IAM rights and the like.

The introductory blog post [New AWS Feature: Consolidated Billing](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/02/new-aws-feature-consolidated-billing.html) provides a good overview, and here is the relevant topic from the [AWS Consolidated Billing Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSConsolidatedBilling/1.0/AWSConsolidatedBillingGuide.html) regarding your apparent use case:

> The paying account is billed for all costs of the linked accounts.
>   **However, each linked account is completely independent in every other
>   way (signing up for services, accessing resources, using AWS Premium
>   Support, etc.).** The paying account owner cannot access data belonging
>   to the linked account owners (e.g., their files in Amazon S3). **Each
>   account owner uses their own AWS credentials to access their resources
>   (e.g., their own AWS Secret Access Key).** *[emphasis mine]*

Obviously this functionality is targeted at larger customers, but depending on your scenario you might be able to come up with a solution to separate your AWS accounts and resources as needed still.

Comment: Following on to the idea to use the "consolidated billing" workaround approach, a person who wants to remain the sys admin in control could retain ownership of all accounts (create one for each user) and just use IAM in each account to grant an individual user the abilities they need. That way you as sys admin can still see when they leave machines running (otherwise they rack up a huge bill without you knowing it till the end of the month. Combine this approach with some 'alert' functionality built into AWS, or use the EC2 APIs to check across all accounts what is running.

Comment: @dmohr - Good point; maybe a bit extreme for larger user bases, but it might sufficiently scale still depending on your needs and, as of today, is also the only option to gain sort of an audit trail (see [Logs for actions on amazon s3 / other AWS services](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15889553/45773) for more on this); if you are only concerned about running instances, you might also want to look into the new [Amazon CloudWatch - Alarm Actions](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/01/amazon-cloudwatch-alarm-actions.html), see my [related answer](http://serverfault.com/a/491074/10305) for details.