# How to start a private instance in EC2 using IAM

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, instance, private, amazon-iam

How can I start an EC2 instance by user A.

and the started instance by user A is unable to be seen by user B.

Can I do this with IAM?

I tried this set:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1341824399883",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute",
        "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but it hides everything including the instances started by user A

Comment: possible duplicate of [Within Amazon AWS IAM, can I restrict a group of users to access/launch/terminate only certain AMIs or instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829506/within-amazon-aws-iam-can-i-restrict-a-group-of-users-to-access-launch-terminat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there are [no Amazon Resource Names(ARNs) for Amazon EC2](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UsingIAM.html): you can't write a policy that applies only to certain EC2 instances.

If you require isolation between the two, the only way I know of is to create a separate AWS account. You can use consolidated billing so that billing is aggregated with your other account, and you can share some things like EBS snapshots between accounts. Most things however can't be shared between accounts.