# How to restrict a user to a specific instance volume in AWS using IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, policy, amazon-iam

I am working on Amazon web services. Designing the custom IAM policies.

I have a user which have restricted access on the instances like he can start,stop the instances. Similarly i want to restrict the user to attach,delete specific volumes.
I have created this policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": ["ec2:DescribeInstances","ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus","ec2:DescribeVolumeAttribute","ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus","ec2:DescribeVolumes"], ,
"Resource": "*"
},
{
"Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"ec2:RunInstances",
"ec2:TerminateInstances",
"ec2:StopInstances",
"ec2:StartInstances",
"ec2:AttachVolume",
"ec2:DetachVolume"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:AccountID:instance/instanceID",
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:AccountID:instance/instanceID",
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:AccountID:instance/instanceID",
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:volume/volID",
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:volume/volID",
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:volume/volID"
}
]
}
```

when I apply this policy it does not show me any volumes.

I get an error:

```
error fetching the volume details.
```

Any lead is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The best way to test/debug IAM policies is by means of the fantastic [IAM Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UsingPolicySimulatorGuide/iam-policy-simulator-guide.html) (see [Using the IAM Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UsingPolicySimulatorGuide/using-iam-policy-simulator.html) for the actual link and instructions). With its help, the solution below can easily be verified to be working correctly.

I recommend to add a dedicated test user to your account with no policies attached (i.e. implicit *Deny All*) and then using the *Mode: New Policy* to assemble and simulate the policy in question, e.g. for the use case at hand:

- use two volumes and allow one via the policy, then simulate the policy with both resources, one will yield *denied* and the other *allowed* for `AttachVolume` and `DetachVolume`

Once satisfied, you can apply the assembled policy to the entities in your account and recheck via *Mode: Existing Policies*.

---

### Initial Answer

I wonder how you have been able to apply this [IAM policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ManagingPolicies.html), insofar it is syntactically invalid JSON (the `Action` field within the first `Statement` lacks any value)?

The syntax error aside, that's also the source of your problem:
As indicated by *TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions*, a few EC2 API actions do not support the comparatively new [Resource-Level Permissions for EC2 and RDS Resources](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/07/resource-permissions-for-ec2-and-rds-resources.html) yet, see this note from [Amazon Resource Names for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#EC2_ARN_Format):

> **Important** Currently, not all API actions support individual ARNs; we'll add support for additional API actions and ARNs for additional
>   Amazon EC2 resources later. For information about which ARNs you can
>   use with which Amazon EC2 API actions, as well as supported condition
>   keys for each ARN, see [Supported Resources and Conditions for Amazon
>   EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources).

You will find that all `ec2:Describe*` actions are indeed absent still from [Supported Resources and Conditions for Amazon EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources) at the time of this writing. This also includes the `ec2:DescribeVolume*` actions, which is why you receive the error.

Fixing the first statement as outlined below should remedy the issue:

```js
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeVolumeAttribute",
        "ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
        "ec2:DescribeVolumes"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:AttachVolume",
        "ec2:DetachVolume"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account number>:volume/<volume id>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is this possible that the user can see all the volumes but can attach,delete a particular Volume. Also he can create volume. Is that possible?

Comment: I am waiting for the response. Kindly respond to my queries whenever u get time. Thanks

Comment: The outlined policy enables your attach/detach scenario just fine, I've updated my answer with instructions on using the IAM Policy Simulator to verify this yourself - you can also allow the creation of volumes, but of course, you do not know the resulting volume id in advance, thus can't include resp. attach/detach permissions upfront. This would require a considerably more sophisticated workflow based on tags, see e.g. section _Partial Workaround_ in my answer to [How to hide instances in EC2 based on tag - using IAM?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18646575/45773) for the conceptual approach.

Comment: Btw., a variation of aforementioned _Partial Workaround_ more closely aligned to your use case is also shown in [Example 4. Allow users to manage particular volumes for particular instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ex4).