# Hide EC2 Instance from other users?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am giving access to AWS Resources to Cognito users, How can I hide other EC2 instances spinned up by other users. Can we filter based on tags. I have a policy in which user can control his resources only but I want to hide others as well.

Comment: Hope this answer may guide you some how Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643555/how-to-hide-instances-in-ec2-based-on-tag-using-iam#answer-18646575

Comment: hide is not happening, i already check this post, but not able to implement this

Comment: When you say "hide", can you provide an example of what command you wish to hide them from? For example, is it the `ListInstances()` API call, or perhaps the EC2 management console? Please be specific since the answer might vary based on which commands you are using.

Comment: I am saying about EC2 Management Console