# How to enable IAM users to set the Name and other custom tags when limited by tag restricted resource-level permissions in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have been playing with configuring tag based resource permissions in EC2, using an approach similar to what is described in the answer to the following question: [Within IAM, can I restrict a group of users to access/launch/terminate only certain EC2 AMIs or instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9854181/7647013)

I have been using this in conjunction with a lambda function to auto tag EC2 instances, setting the `Owner` and `PrincipalId` based on the IAM user who called the associated `ec2:RunInstances` action. The approach I have been following for this is documented in the following AWS blog post: [How to Automatically Tag Amazon EC2 Resources in Response to API Events](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-tag-amazon-ec2-resources-in-response-to-api-events/)

The combination of these two approaches has resulted in my restricted user permissions for EC2 looking like this, in my CloudFormation template:

```
LimitedEC2Policy:
Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
Properties:
  PolicyName: UserLimitedEC2
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action: ec2:RunInstances
        Resource:
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:subnet/${PrivateSubnetA}'
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:subnet/${PrivateSubnetB}'
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:subnet/${PrivateSubnetC}'
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:security-group/${BasicSSHAccessSecurityGroup.GroupId}'
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:key-pair/${AuthorizedKeyPair}'
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:network-interface/*'
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:instance/*'
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:volume/*'
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}::image/ami-*'
        Condition:
          StringLikeIfExists:
            ec2:Vpc: !Ref Vpc
          StringLikeIfExists:
            ec2:InstanceType: !Ref EC2AllowedInstanceTypes
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - ec2:TerminateInstances
          - ec2:StopInstances
          - ec2:StartInstances
        Resource:
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:instance/*'
        Condition:
          StringEquals:
            ec2:ResourceTag/Owner: !Ref UserName
  Users:
    - !Ref IAMUser
```

These IAM permissions restricts users to running EC2 instances within a limited set of subnets, within a single VPC and security group. Users are then only able to start/stop/terminate instances which have been tagged with their IAM user in the `Owner` tag.

What I'd like to be able to do is allow users to also create and delete any additional tags on their EC2 resources, such as setting the `Name` tag. What I can't work out is how I can do this without also enabling them to change the `Owner` and `PrincipalId` tags on resources they don't "own".

Is there a way one can limit the `ec2:createTags` and `ec2:deleteTags` actions to prevent users from setting certain tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much sifting through the AWS EC2 documentation I found the following: [Resource-Level Permissions for Tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html?shortFooter=true#supported-iam-actions-tagging)

This gives the example:

> Use with the `ForAllValues` modifier to enforce specific tag keys if
>   they are provided in the request (if tags are specified in the
>   request, only specific tag keys are allowed; no other tags are
>   allowed). For example, the tag keys environment or cost-center are
>   allowed:
>
> ```
> "ForAllValues:StringEquals": { "aws:TagKeys": ["environment","cost-center"] }
> ```

Since what I want to achive is essentially the opposite of this (allow users to specify all tags, with the exception of specific tag keys) I have been able to prevent users from creating/deleting the Owner and PrincipalId tags by adding the following `PolicyDocument` statement to my user policy in my CloudFormation template:

```
- Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - ec2:CreateTags
      - ec2:DeleteTags
    Resource:
      - !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*/*'
    Condition:
      "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals":
        aws:TagKeys:
          - "Owner"
          - "PrincipalId"
```

This permits users to create/delete any tags they wish, so long as they aren't the `Owner` or `PrincipalId`.